# Who was Penny mentioning in S02E04 "The Griffin Equivalency"?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In *"The Griffin Equivalency"*, a 2nd season episode of ***The Big Bang Theory***, Howard, Sheldon, Raj and Leonard were dining at the Cheese Cake Factory (Penny is also present in the scene, of course). They were discussing about Raj being featured in the People's magazine.

Here she says:

> Raj is gonna be in the people magazine. **He didn't have to knock up one
>   of the spare sisters.**

So, **who/what incident was Penny talking about there?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [quote](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-2-episode-04-the-griffin-equivalency/) is actually:

> Come on, this is huge, Raj is going to be in People magazine. And he didn’t even have to knock up one of the Spears sisters.

She is referencing [Britney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney_Spears) and [Jamie Lynn Spears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Lynn_Spears), who are sisters.  Both are also singers and pretty famous, not sure if it has to do with it exactly, but they both were actually on magazine covers after they had their babies, Britney was even on People Magazine's cover when she had her's.  Below are both magazine covers just for added effect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ahh!  Looks like I mis-hear the `Spears` part then :)

Comment: @Dawny33 You probably couldn't process it after the awkward laugh track. *cringe*